# Using foreign key attributes in Angular template

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I use Django for backend (Django Rest Framework) and Angular for frontend. In the backend, I have 2 models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

which I serialize accordingly:

```
class CategorySerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model   = Category
        fields = '__all__'

class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model   = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then in the component template I want to print the title of the category for a specific post:

```
<li *ngFor='let post of posts'>
  <div *ngIf='post'>
    <p>{{ post.category.title }}</p>
    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
  </div>
</li>
```

My classes are:

```
export class Post {
  id: number;
  category: Category;
  content: string;
}

export class Category {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}
```

Why `{{ post.category.title }}` doesn't work, while `{{ post.content }}` works? Is it an issue of my serialization or of my Angular classes?

edit: The API View:

```
class PostListCreateAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset            = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class    = PostSerializer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new serializer `RetrivePostSerializer`.

Use `CategorySerializer` to serialize Related field *category* in your `RetrivePostSerializer`

```
class RetrivePostSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model   = Post
        fields = ('id', 'category', 'content')
```

Use different serializer for the GET and POST, override `get_serializer_class` method

```
class PostListCreateAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
       if self.request.method == 'POST':
          return PostSerializer
       return RetrivePostSerializer
```

Your `PostSerializer` will be as earlier

```
class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model   = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: I tried this but then in my PostCreateAPIView (browsable API) it asks me to post a new Category as well, which leads to error:

Comment: updated my answer, add `read_only=True` to CategorySerializer constructor

Comment: Ok, that was my first action too. But this causes to add category=null for every new Post I create.

Comment: You need to use two different serializer one for creation and another for retrieval

Comment: updated my answer, you need to create a new serializer `RetrivePostSerializer` and use it in your view

Comment: Could you post a sample for the PostSerializer? Because right now I can't get it to work this way.

Comment: You PostSerializer will be as earlier